# Is it forbidden to laugh when playing in a chess tournament?

Tags: rules, etiquette

I have read [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/what-are-the-essentials-of-chess-etiquette-in-a-serious-over-the-board-tourname), but it still hasn’t filled my brain yet. When I play chess, sometimes I'm often laughing and putting some pressure on my opponent. Is it forbidden in legal game? Is there a rule about it?

Comment: try crying perhaps ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FIDE [Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=171&view=article):

> **11.5** It is forbidden to *distract* or *annoy* the opponent in any manner whatsoever. This includes unreasonable claims, unreasonable offers of a draw or the introduction of a *source of noise* into the playing area.

Distracting or annoying the opponent in any manner (other than making good moves!) is forbidden, and making noise is forbidden. So laughing in order to give pressure to your opponent is forbidden.

Comment: thanks. I will ask new question about it. I found a leak on those punishments (12.9).

Comment: may be you can follow up your answer now on [my new question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/fide-asking-about-fide-punishments-leak-on-point-12-9).

Because there are a leak (as benefit) that I can use when I got punishment by verse 2 (eventhough I don't know what punishment that I will get. hahaha.).